# how to hide and show one button after clicked on another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, buttonclick

I'm gonna use two buttons in one page. Something like when we click on first one then second button will be appeared instead on first one and if we click on second one then first one will be appeared. without losing function of the button.

here is my button code:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="menu2.toggle()" class="sideviewtoggle myButton">Test 1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="menu3.toggle()" class="sideviewtoggle myButton">Test 2</button>
```

For example:

**Test 1** is default, and **test 2** is hidden, if we click on **test 1** then **test 1** will disappear and instead **test 2** will be appeared and again if we click on **test 2** then it will be disappeared and instead **test 1** will be appeared. without losing onclick function of these two buttons.

Here is my toggle menu function, if we click on test 1 button then this page: **togglemenu.php** will open and if we click on test 2, then **togglemenu2.php** will open as well.

```
jQuery(function(){
menu2 = new sidetogglemenu({  
id: 'togglemenu2', 
position: 'right',
source: 'togglemenu.php', 
revealamt: -5
})

jQuery(function(){
menu3 = new sidetogglemenu({  
id: 'togglemenu3', 
position: 'right',
source: 'togglemenu2.php', 
revealamt: -5
})
```

How to make it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.getElementById('yourButtonId').style.display='none';` to hide `document.getElementById('yourButtonId').style.display='';` to show

Comment: This is just for show and hide button, I need a function to hide and show after click. and is it possible to get element by class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By without losing the function of the button, I assume you mean that you want to keep the menu toggle.  What you need to do is define your own function, and inside that function, toggle your menu AND perform the show/hide that you desire.

Under the assumption that you are new to javascript, I wrote this example to be straightforward.

```js
//With a function, I am able to perform multiple tasks 
function SwitchButtons(buttonId) {
  var hideBtn, showBtn, menuToggle;
  if (buttonId == 'button1') {
    menuToggle = 'menu2';
    showBtn = 'button2';
    hideBtn = 'button1';
  } else {
    menuToggle = 'menu3';
    showBtn = 'button1';
    hideBtn = 'button2';
  }
  //I don't have your menus, so this is commented out.  just uncomment for your usage
  // document.getElementById(menuToggle).toggle(); //step 1: toggle menu
  document.getElementById(hideBtn).style.display = 'none'; //step 2 :additional feature hide button
  document.getElementById(showBtn).style.display = ''; //step 3:additional feature show button


}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="SwitchButtons('button1');" class="sideviewtoggle myButton">Test 1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="SwitchButtons('button2');" class="sideviewtoggle myButton" style='display:none;'>Test 2</button>
```

Comment: You code is well, but you used SwitchButtons onclick function, How to keep my onlclick function, I mean how to add menu2.toggle()  and menu3.toggle()   into your code?

Comment: it's in there, look at the commented out line (I commented it out because I didn't have those menus, so it would have given a script error)

Comment: actually now hide and show is working well but my onclick function doesn't work. that's why.

Comment: can you post your menus html as well?

Comment: and also, did you uncomment this?`document.getElementById(menuToggle).toggle(); `

Comment: I updated my question, the query onclick function will open two separate pages, as you can see in above

Comment: here is also my html button based on your code: <button style="" id="button1" onclick="SwitchButtons('button1');" class="sideviewtoggle myButton">Test 1</button>

Comment: Thanks, It's working well now, I added onlick function like this: onclick=\"menu2.toggle() ,  SwitchButtons('button1');\"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility you might consider is, rather than hiding/unhiding buttons, you could use JavaScript to change the look and functioning of the button dynamically.

```js
function toggle(ev) {
  ev.target.dataset.state = ev.target.dataset.state === 'menu1' ? 'menu2' : 'menu1';
  ev.target.textContent = ev.target.textContent === 'Test 1' ? 'Test 2' : 'Test 1';
  if (ev.target.dataset.state === 'menu1') {
    // Add code to display Menu 1 here.
  } else if (ev.target.dataset.state === 'menu2') {
    // Add code to display Menu 2 here.
  }
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

```html
<button type=button name=toggleButton data-state=menu1>Test 1</button>
```

The way in which you hide or display the different menus could follow a similar approach as well. So you could have a `toggleButton` function, and inside that function, call a `toggleMenu` function.

Comment: what library are you using for this? it's not working on html page, i added latest j query 2.1.1 but doesn't work.

Comment: do you have another button earlier on the page? the queryselector might be adding the listener to that instead. try giving the button an id and making the queryselector target that id instead.

Comment: There're only two buttons on that page, test1 and test2,, I added ID for each of them id="button1" and id="button2", hide and show buttons should read based on ID not onlick function, cause as you can see in above @dwhieb, onlick function doesn't work correctly

Comment: just to clarify, what I'm suggesting is only using 1 button, not 2. The button will change how it's displaying each time you click it. Also, if you're using `addEventListener`, make sure you're not using the `onclick=` attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

i think if your using `Jquery` it's better create a hidden css class

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

and remove or add with method `.addClass() or .removeClass()`

Example:

html file:

```
<button id="hideMenu" class="sideviewtoggle myButton">Test 1</button>
```

js file

```
$('#hideMenu').on('click', function() {
  $('#menu-to-hide').addClass('hidden');
  //or
  $('#menu-to-show').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: could you please give me an example of using css with jquery?how to use addclass and removeclass in jquery ?